# Badness: why 100.|z|^3 instead of 100 z^2?

Tags: tex-core, badness

As written [here](https://www.fi.muni.cz/lemma/PB029/slides/2016-11-23.pdf) on page 158, the badness penalty is `100|z|^3` instead of `100z^2`. Why is "3" in the exponent when we take the **absolute value** of z?

Here `z=(L-w)/w^+`, where L is the required width and w is the width and `w^+` is the stretchability.

Comment: You're really going to need to put some context here.  And translate it to English, for those of us who can't read that language.

Comment: @Teepeemm Is my **EDIT** enough to your request ?

Comment: Is this slide talking about the badness computation in TeX?  You seem to have two questions: why 3 instead of 2, and why the absolute value.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes, badness in TeX. And right I've joined them but the 2 questions are more precise.

Comment: Not historian. But that is just a cost function for the line-breaking algorithm to optimize against. Judging from Knuth's choice it is probably the case that if you give small violations penalties as big as z^2 the algorithm will favor one big violations over multiple small violations. But, from human's perspective, we tend to notice a~~~really~~~bad~~~line~~~like~~~this before we notice that there are multiple mediocrely bad lines.

Comment: This is what the "Breaking Paragraphs Into Lines" paper says on this topic: "Let us
therefore give a quantitative evaluation of the badness of the jth line by finding a formula that is nearly zero when Irj| is small but grows rapidly when IrjI takes values
exceeding 1. Experience with TeX has shown that good results are obtained if we
define the badness of line j as follows:", etc. That is, the cubic function grows more rapidly, and this works better. I believe he also mentions this in one of the available videos.

Comment: your question is hard to understand, the value is raised to the power 3, why do you think 2 would be more natural, it could be 5 or 6 or 2.5 , but it is 3

Comment: If it's possible for z to be negative (I don't know because I haven't read the TeX source) then you need the absolute value in order to have positive badness when z is not 0. As to why the exponent is 3 and not 2 or something else - probably a free aesthetic choice.

Comment: The computation of badness gives always a number between 0 and 10000,
so that lines that stretch and lines that shrink can be compared. The
reason why it is a cube is explained by ShreevatsaR's comment. But
your interpretation of $z$ is wrong. On page 157 of the link to the
presentation I found $r$ which stands for the ratio of change of
glue. As glue can stretch and shrink you should look at both cases: If
$w$ is larger than $L$ you don't divide by $w^+$ but by $w^-$ (p. 156)
and the result is negative in your notation thus the absolute value
must be used.